# PHP - How to handle 'utf-16', us-ascii encoded html string to save correctly in DomDocument?

Tags: php, html, domdocument, utf-16

I am working on a PHP project which fetches emails and displays them on the screen. In an email it fetches the following html :

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">

    <style type="text/css">
          TD {
          font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial, "Sans Serif";
          font-size: 10pt;
          }
          BODY {
          font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial, "Sans Serif";
          font-size: 10pt;
          }
        </style>



    </head>

      <body bgcolor="#eeeeee"><img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/1pixel.gif?gen=20181128"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" bgcolor="white" align="center" style="border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid; border-right: 1px #CCCCCC solid; border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;">
      <tr>

        <td height="20" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td width="20"></td>

        <td><a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Track.aspx?site=2018112820201&amp;tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937" style="text-decoration: underline;"><img border="0" alt="Trade Me Logo" width="246" height="48" src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/new-brand-2016/common/tm-logo-2016-246x48-v1.gif?gen=2018112820201"></a><img src="https://api.trademe.co.nz/tracking/collect?evt=open&amp;tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937&amp;tid=EB71C99D-BEB4-445F-B62B-C172AC5A4CF4"></td>

        <td align="center"></td>

        <td width="20"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td width="20"></td>

        <td colspan="2">

          <hr size="0" color="#CCCCCC">

          <center><small>Security Note: Trade Me will never ask you for your password via email</small></center>

          <hr size="0" color="#CCCCCC">

        </td>

        <td width="20"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td width="20"></td>

        <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;"><small>

      This is an automated email regarding listing #: 1847238571</small><br><br>

    Hi Matthew,

    <br><br><div>

      A member has asked a question on your listing for "2.4KW 2400W 3KVA 24VDC Pure Sine Wave Power Inverter Solar Caravan Off Grid LCD".

    </div><br><table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">

            <tr>

              <td align="center" width="20"><img width="20" height="20" alt="" src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/icon_question.gif">&nbsp;</td>

              <td>what is the warranty like? &nbsp;&nbsp;<small><i>posted by:&nbsp;</i></small>&nbsp;<b><a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Members/Listings.aspx?member=4187691&amp;tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937" style="text-decoration: underline;">matihegarty</a></b>

    (<a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Members/Feedback.aspx?member=4187691&amp;tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937" style="text-decoration: underline;">5</a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Members/Feedback.aspx?member=4187691&amp;tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"><img align="absmiddle" border="0" src="https://www.trademe.co.nz/images/star.gif"></a>)

  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>8:54 pm, Wed 28 Nov</small></td>

            </tr>

          </table><br><br><center><b><font size="3"><a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/a.asp?id=1847238571&amp;qna=true#qna&amp;tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937" style="text-decoration: underline;">Answer this question</a></font></b></center><br><br><div>

      We recommend you answer all questions on your listings to help buyers make informed decisions. Questions on vehicle listings created in Trade Me Motors will be displayed automatically. For other listings, questions will only be displayed if answered.

    </div><br><br>

    Happy trading!

    <br><br>

    The Trade Me team

    <br><a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/?tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937" style="text-decoration: underline;">www.trademe.co.nz</a><br><br><small>

      If you don't wish to receive these emails or prefer plain text email, please update your

      <a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/MyTradeMe/EmailOptions.aspx?tm=email&amp;et=201&amp;mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937" style="text-decoration: underline;">email options</a></small></td>

        <td width="20"></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td colspan="3">

          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="background-color:White;">

            <tr>

              <td align="center"><br><small><img width="7" height="8" src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/3/common/triangle.gif">&nbsp;<font color="#666666">advertisement</font></small><br><br></td>

            </tr>

          </table>

          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="background-color:#9A9A9A;">

            <tr>

              <td><a href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Link.aspx?i=101247"><img style="border-width:0;" src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/photoserver/adserver/TMI0003-700x70-mates-FA.png?e=" alt="" width="700" height="70"></a></td>

            </tr>

          </table>

        </td>

      </tr>

    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

My program does this :

```
    $cleanMessage = new DOMDocument();
    @$cleanMessage->loadHTML($this->bodyHTML); //To clean the html code for unclosed td table tags and other 

    $this->message = $cleanMessage->saveHTML();
```

But my output is :

> ��<�!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> <�html><�head><�meta
>   http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16"><�style
>   type="text/css"> TD { font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial, "Sans Serif";
>   font-size: 10pt; } BODY { font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial, "Sans
>   Serif"; font-size: 10pt; } <�/style><�/head><�body
>   bgcolor="#eeeeee"><�img width="1" height="1" alt=""
>   src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/1pixel.gif?gen=20181128"><�table
>   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" bgcolor="white"
>   align="center" style="border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid; border-right:
>   1px #CCCCCC solid; border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;"><�tr><�td
>   height="20" colspan="4">�<�/td> <�/tr><�tr><�td width="20"><�/td>
>   <�td><�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Track.aspx?site=2018112820201&tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"
>   style="text-decoration: underline;"><�img border="0" alt="Trade Me
>   Logo" width="246" height="48"
>   src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/new-brand-2016/common/tm-logo-2016-246x48-v1.gif?gen=2018112820201"><�/a><�img
>   src="https://api.trademe.co.nz/tracking/collect?evt=open&tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937&tid=EB71C99D-BEB4-445F-B62B-C172AC5A4CF4"><�/td>
>   <�td align="center"><�/td> <�td width="20"><�/td> <�/tr><�tr><�td
>   width="20"><�/td> <�td colspan="2"> <�hr size="0"
>   color="#CCCCCC"><�center><�small>Security Note: Trade Me will never
>   ask you for your password via email<�/small><�/center> <�hr size="0"
>   color="#CCCCCC"><�/td> <�td width="20"><�/td> <�/tr><�tr><�td
>   width="20"><�/td> <�td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px;
>   padding-top: 10px;"><�small> This is an automated email regarding
>   listing #: 1847238571<�/small><�br><�br> Hi Matthew, <�br><�br><�div>
>   A member has asked a question on your listing for "2.4KW 2400W 3KVA
>   24VDC Pure Sine Wave Power Inverter Solar Caravan Off Grid LCD".
>   <�/div><�br><�table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"
>   border="0"><�tr><�td align="center" width="20"><�img width="20"
>   height="20" alt=""
>   src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/icon_question.gif">�<�/td>
>   <�td>what is the warranty like? ��<�small><�i>posted
>   by:�<�/i><�/small>�<�b><�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Members/Listings.aspx?member=4187691&tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"
>   style="text-decoration: underline;">matihegarty<�/a><�/b> (<�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Members/Feedback.aspx?member=4187691&tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"
>   style="text-decoration: underline;">5<�/a>�<�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Members/Feedback.aspx?member=4187691&tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"><�img
>   align="absmiddle" border="0"
>   src="https://www.trademe.co.nz/images/star.gif"><�/a>) ���<�small>8:54
>   pm, Wed 28 Nov<�/small><�/td>
>   <�/tr><�/table><�br><�br><�center><�b><�font size="3"><�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/a.asp?id=1847238571&qna=true#qna&tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"
>   style="text-decoration: underline;">Answer this
>   question<�/a><�/font><�/b><�/center><�br><�br><�div> We recommend you
>   answer all questions on your listings to help buyers make informed
>   decisions. Questions on vehicle listings created in Trade Me Motors
>   will be displayed automatically. For other listings, questions will
>   only be displayed if answered. <�/div><�br><�br> Happy trading!
>   <�br><�br> The Trade Me team <�br><�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/?tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"
>   style="text-decoration:
>   underline;">www.trademe.co.nz<�/a><�br><�br><�small> If you don't wish
>   to receive these emails or prefer plain text email, please update your
>   <�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/MyTradeMe/EmailOptions.aspx?tm=email&et=201&mt=75D6A1C7-4DEA-4B06-A3E9-6A12C1B41937"
>   style="text-decoration: underline;">email options<�/a><�/small><�/td>
>   <�td width="20"><�/td> <�/tr><�tr><�td colspan="3"> <�table
>   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center"
>   style="background-color:White;"><�tr><�td
>   align="center"><�br><�small><�img width="7" height="8"
>   src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/images/3/common/triangle.gif">�<�font
>   color="#666666">advertisement<�/font><�/small><�br><�br><�/td>
>   <�/tr><�/table><�table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
>   width="100%" align="center"
>   style="background-color:#9A9A9A;"><�tr><�td><�a
>   href="https://www.trademe.co.nz/Link.aspx?i=101247"><�img
>   style="border-width:0;"
>   src="https://trademe.tmcdn.co.nz/photoserver/adserver/TMI0003-700x70-mates-FA.png?e="
>   alt="" width="700" height="70"><�/a><�/td> <�/tr><�/table><�/td>
>   <�/tr><�/table><�/body><�/html>

I tried :

1.

```
$this->bodyHTML = mb_convert_encoding($this->bodyHTML,'UTF-8','utf-16');
$this->bodyHTML = mb_convert_encoding($this->bodyHTML,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'); //both lines together
```

2. `$this->bodyHTML = mb_convert_encoding($this->bodyHTML,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-16');`

But it still displays garbled or chinese type characters.

What is the right way to display this html correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html replace charset`utf-16` with `utf-8` or `ISO-8859-1` if you see strange characters.

```
$this->bodyHTML = str_replace("charset=utf-16","charset=utf-8", $this->bodyHTML);
```